# How to display string in ListBox using MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I have a `ListBox` on a WPF form. I would like to display a list of string items horizontally. I have a `Grid` that holds my `ListBox` control.

When I run the form it displays the name of the encapsulating object: **ProjectName.Folder.Category** instead of the string object within it.

`ViewModelLocator`

```
public CategoryViewModel CategoryViewModel
{
    get
    {
        if (categoryviewModel == null)
        {
            categoryviewModel = new CategoryViewModel();
            categoryviewModel.ListData.Clear();
            categoryviewModel.ListData.Add(new Category { MyCategory = "new categroy1" });
            categoryviewModel.ListData.Add(new Category { MyCategory = "new categroy2" });
            categoryviewModel.ListData.Add(new Category { MyCategory = "new categroy3" });
            categoryviewModel.ListData.Add(new Category { MyCategory = "new categroy4" });
            categoryviewModel.ListData.Add(new Category { MyCategory = "new categroy5" });
            categoryviewModel.ListData.Add(new Category { MyCategory = "new categroy6" });
        }
        return categoryviewModel;
    }
}
```

`Model`

```
class Category
{
    public String MyCategory { get; set; }
}
```

`MainPage.xaml`

```
<Grid>
    <my:featureControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                       x:Name="featureControl1" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="332" 
                       Loaded="featureControl1_Loaded" />
</Grid>
```

`Control.xaml`

```
<UserControl x:Class="AmebaPrototype.UI.Longlist.CategoryControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="1280">
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewModelLocator},Path=CategoryViewModel}">

    <ListBox Height="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1280" ItemsSource="{Binding ListData}" >
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>        
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `DisplayMemberPath` in your `ListBox`

Comment: ...or specify an `ItemTemplate`.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to have done the trick.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListBoxTemplate">
    <TextBlock x:Name="black"  Text="{Binding MyCategory}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: It will work, but just putting DisplayMemberPath="MyCategory" on your ListBox line is a lot simpler :)

Comment: Yep just did that, Thanks @DeanChalk . I will accept your answer in  a couple mins when it lets me  :)